# window.pageYOffset is always 0 with overflow-x: hidden

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm creating a webpage that has some off-screen content that only needs to slide in at specific times. To achieve this I'm setting `overflow-x: hidden` on `html, body`. This way the user cannot scroll left or right to get at the content.

However, at some point in the application I also need the amount that the user has scrolled down yet. As far as I know `window.pageYOffset` is one of the most reliable ways of doing this.

However, when I set the `overflow-x` rule. `window.pageYOffset` is always equal to `0`.

Shouldn't these things be pretty unrelated to each other? How can I fix this?

I've tested this on Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

I've tried `document.documentElement.scrollTop` but this only worked on Firefox.

NB:

I was not able to reproduce the problem with a very simple example.
My app also has the main content in a container that has `position: absolute`. If I remove this, everything works.

So it seems to be the combination of `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` and `postion: absolute` on the `.content` inside the body.

I cannot easily get rid of the position absolute requirement however, since
different `.content` containers should be able to be placed over one another.

Edit 2:
It gets even weirder: I've got a `transform: translate(0,0)` set on `.content` to be be able to transition to some other value later. If I remove this, everything works fine! Yet another seemingly unrelated css
property that interferes.

Comment: I found my issue was that I had `overflow-x: hidden` on both html and body. If I moved it to just html, it was fine. However, IE11 would now ignore it, meaning I had to add an additional `overflow-x: hidden` to an internal element. As another note, it was due to adding flex and sticky footer stuff that caused this bug to manifest itself. Translates and position absolutes probably affect it too.

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem and i resolved it after a long search.

The problem seems to comes from `overflow-x: hidden` inside the body. So to fix this strange behavior i used a wrapper like this :

```
<body>
   <div class="myWrapper">
      All your content here
   </div>
</body>
```

and then I moved the overflow attribute in the wrapper's CSS instead of letting it in html, body :

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

With this little trick when i scan my srollTop propertie now located in my wrapper element, the result is no longer 0 but the real value.
Without that it doesn't work on Chrome ...

Answer (score 11):

I have a similar issue where the parent of the element where the overflow happens has `overflow: hidden;`. It's not a CSS attribute I can just remove.

My solution to this is, instead of getting `window.pageYOffset` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, I get the `Event` object when the scroll is happening. From the `Event` object, we can get `scrollTop` property, like `e.srcElement.scrollTop`

My event handler looks something like:

```
onScroll(e) {
  if (e.srcElement.scrollTop > 8) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Then, bind this event to the element where the scroll is happening.

Comment: In my case, I use e.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollTop otherwise I receive undefined. It work on Chrome.

Comment: The event doesn't fire with the `overflow-x: hidden`, so the issue remains the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

just go with your container instead of a window and take `scrollTop` from that event.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.abc');

fromEvent(container,'scroll').pipe(
map ((event) => event.srcElement['scrollTop'])
)
```

works for me