# Auto hide Angular Material toolbar (top navigation bar) on scroll down

Tags: css, angular, typescript, user-experience

I currently have an Angular app that uses standard toolbar as the top navigation. [image: picture of top part of my web app]

Now I would like the navigation bar to scroll up with the user when they scroll down and reappear when they scroll up.

I've tried using `window.pageYOffset` but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050548/window-pageyoffset-is-always-0-with-overflow-x-hidden), this value always returns `0`.

I've made a Stackblitz with my current setup for my navbar [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aaimvw).

Answer (score 3):

**The no-JS way**

You can do the trick only using CSS. This will hide the navbar progressively as soon as you start scrolling.

```css
.exemple-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: -200px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

**The onScroll way**

Set a scroll listener on your container div, and add a class to the navbar depending on the scroll direction.

```js
scrollTop = 0;
hideNav = false;

onScroll(event) {
  this.hideNav = this.scrollTop < event.target.scrollTop;
  this.scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.nav.hide-nav {
  display: none; /* You can play on opacity for nice transitions*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">

  <div class="nav" [class.hide-nav]="hideNav">
     <!-- Nav -->
  </div>

<!--content-->

</div>
```

This can work with an HostListener as well, but the parent node of your component has to be scrollable (which is not the case in your example)

Answer (score -1):

You can look at this, this is a best example which i found -  https://netbasal.com/reactive-sticky-header-in-angular-12dbffb3f1d3